# How to make the expression simple in R?

Tags: r

How can i make the expression more simple in R?

```
0.64-0.0205*(c(qnorm(0.005),-qnorm(0.005)))
```

Comment: You are getting down voted as this question is unclear. What do you mean by `more simple`?

Comment: I took it as a request for an expression that involved fewer function calls or fewer keystrokes or both. R-golf or R-more-efficient if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0.64-0.0205*c(1,-1)*qnorm(0.005)
```